# include aspx file in other aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
<% if (Session["desig"].ToString() == "Developer"){%>
    <td>
        <select name='zone' id="zone" onchange="showLoc(this.value,'mlodg_loc')"> 
            <option value="Select Zone">Select Zone</option>
            <option value="East">East</option>
            <option value="West">West</option>
            <option value="North">North</option>
            <option value="South1">South1</option>
            <option value="South2">South2</option>
            <option value="South3">South3</option>
        </select>
    </td>  
<%}
  else 
  {%>
        <td>
          <select name='zone' id="Select1" onchange="showLoc(this.value,'mlodg_loc')"> 
              <option value="Select Zone">Select Zone</option>
              <option value="<%#Session["zone"]%>"><%# Session["zone"].ToString() %></option>
          </select>
        </td>
<%}%>
```

the code above is working fine if I am writing it directly, I tried to write this code in other file and in main file i did `Response.WriteFile("zone.aspx")`

How can i include it is there any way to include and also would like to know a better way to write the above statements.

Thankyou

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642624/how-to-include-aspx-page-in-another-aspx-page-in-asp-net

Comment: isn't .ascx a viable option?

Answer (score 5):

`UserControls` are there in asp.net for this purpose, make a **.ascx** file for this piece of code u have, and use it as a control anywhere.

Comment: I think I have to write out the html with response if i use UserControl, wright?

Comment: It outputs your html on it's own you don't have to do anything for that except for defining :  
`<%@ Register Src="YourFile.ascx" TagPrefix="YOURTAGPREFIX"  TagName="YOURTAGNAME" %>`
and using : `<YOURTAGPREFIX:YOURTAGNAME ID="IDFORTHISCONTROL" runat="server" />`
this will get you started : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728784(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

[`Response.WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx) just writes the filecontents into the Http response stream, without parsing it.

Although it is possible to use [Server Side includes in asp.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3207d0e3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (`<!--#include file="xxx.ext" -->`), this has an asp-classic code smell to it IMO.

The better way to get re-use of `.aspx` components is by using a [User Control (.ascx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc(v=vs.85).aspx).

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959125/asp-net-code-within-include-not-executing)

**Update**

`Response.WriteFile` is fine for plain Html, .css or .js, but not for code containing c# or referencing .Net objects (you've used `Session` in your code), e.g.

```
Response.WriteFile("HtmlSnippet.html")
```

where `HtmlSnippet.html` is

```
<p>In breaking news, scientists have discovered a planet in 
     <a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Centauri_Bb'>Alpha Centauri</a>
</p>
```

Using a Server Side Include, e.g. `<!--#include file="file.inc" -->` would allow you to do put something like this in file.inc:

```
<% if (Session["desig"].ToString() == "Developer"){ %>
   You are a Developer!!
<% } %>
```

However, the recommendation is to use a User Control (`.ascx`), which allows you to do much the same as the server side include, but just in a much more reusable, object oriented, and testable fashion. Your reusable Control will be a first class object, with properties, methods and be able to raise events. You'll need to do some research here.

Comment: I did not understand how to do that with .ascx, as i have to generate html. A simple piece of code might help. Thansk

Comment: Thanks, the server side include is perfect for those of us who want a basic jump page that executes some javascript after load to do testing.

Answer (score 0):

Response.WriteFile does not process the code on the server side. It simply takes the contents of html and pipes it to the browser. 
If your code contains code blocks that must be processed by the server you can use this handy feature:

```
<div ID="menuContent" runat="server">
    <!-- #Include virtual="/menu.aspx" -->
</div>
```

In my menu.aspx file I have raw html and some C# codeblocks and ASP will resolve those after inserting the content into the page. Great huh?